Is this statement about differentiable function wrong?
For those, who closed the question: please check the last comments under it. I can move it to the post, if it is needed

In Analysis book I read it is stated (page 230, third article. It is in Russian, I provide translation):

Definition D1. Function $f:E\rightarrow R$, defined on the set $E ⊂ R$ is called differentiable at a point $a \in E$, that is a limit point of $E$, if there exists such linear, relatively argument growth $x-a$ function $A*(x-a)$, that growth $f(x)-f(a)$ of the function $f$ is represented as:
$$f(x)-f(a) = A(x-a) + o(x-a),\space \space x\rightarrow a, x \in E \space (9)$$
In other words, function $f$ is differentiable at point $a$, if the change of its values in the neighborhood of $a$ is linear with a precision up to a fix, that is infinitely small, relatively to the value $x-a$

I agree with what is written in the first paragraph and with math symbols.
"in other words" alternative formulation provides only qualitative characteristic of the differential:

change of its values in the neighborhood of $a$
is linear

i.e. states that function growth is linear (due to linear differential) with precision $o(x-a)$, but does not provide quantitative characteristic - does not state that differential (and hence function growth) should be infinitively small at $x\rightarrow a$, hence allowing it to be not infinitely small, hence allowing function, that I provided below to be considerable as differentiable.
"in other words" formulation does not make restriction, according to which, small changes of an argument will produce small changes of function value, so it should be:

In other words, function $f$
is differentiable at point $a$
, if the change of its values in the neighborhood of $a$
is infinitely small and linear with a precision up to a fix, that is infinitely small, relatively to the value $x−a$


Consider some function $f$, which value difference $f(x-a)-f(a), \space x\rightarrow a$ at some $a$ equals, for example $5$, literally. Prove with "in other words" formulation from above that it is not differentiable at $x=a$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is Weierstraß's formulation of differentiability. $o(x-a)$ here means
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{r(x-a)}{\|x-a\|}=0
$$
where $r(x-a)$ is the remainder, the error we make by using the linear approximation $A.$ How you personally describe it in words is likely a matter of taste. I find the wording acceptable: "fix [$=r(x-a)$], that is infinitely small [$\stackrel{x\to a}{\longrightarrow }0$], relatively to [=divided by] the value $x−a.$

"How you personally describe it in words is likely a matter of taste" - what it? You meant "it" - i.e. what is the $o(x-a)$?

"it" is the fix: $o(x-a)=r(x-a)$ such that the limit $\lim_{x-a}\frac{r(x-a)}{|x-a|}$ vanishes. See Landau notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Then, please reread the "in other words" formulation. It does not describe little-o, it describes differentiability

Or, please, check the update below my post and try to prove

Proof is here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstra%C3%9Fsche_Zerlegungsformel
You can use Google Chrome to translate it for you.

The formulation is correct: linear approximation with a remainder or fix that is $r(x-a)=o(x-a).$

It is not, seems it does not use definition, provided by author, I mentioned in the post. Using math, this definition can be written as $$f(x)-f(a) = g(x-a) + o(x-a),\space \space x\rightarrow a, x \in E$$, where $g(x)$ is linear function with uncertain properties.

@isagsadvb I realized reading this comment that the confusion might have stemmed from the term “linear”. The text refers to “linear” as in preserving scalar multiplication and addition ($f$ is linear if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(cx)=cf(x)$), not “linear function” as in high school math, which are functions of the form $f(x)=ax+b$. If $b$ is nonzero, then those linear functions are in fact NOT linear in the first mentioned sense!

@Divide1918, fine, but if You mean by all of this, that $b$ is the fix part, and it is not little-o, as You shown, considering $f(x)=|x|$, then, as I shown You in the comments below my post - fix is zero for $f(x)=|x|$, i.e. $b$ is zero

@isagsadvb b is not the fix part, there is no fix part n the above comment, because it’s not about the derivative, only about the meaning of “ linear”. For what the fix part is refer to my comment under the question, it cannot be b as putting it as the fix term fails the definition.

Roughly, this is not an answer, I rather overview answer and comments of @Marius S.L. and @peek-a-boo.
First user seems to confuse function value growth
$$\Delta y=f(x+h)-f(x)=df(x)+o(h)=f'(x)h+o(h),\space h \rightarrow 0$$
with the differential of a function
$$df(x)=f'(x)h$$
because the "in other words" formulation, that my post dedicated to, is about linearity of function value growth, but its linearity comes not from little-o, but from linear differential (little-o just make a precision of $\Delta y$), so little-o has nothing to do with the question at all.

I asked @peek-a-boo to prove that the function from the bottom of my post is not differentiable at given point using the "in other words" formulation, if such formulation is correct. User stated that given function is not differentiable, since it is not continuous.
Of course, "in other words" formulation did not mention anything about continuity of the function, and it seems like User has conceptual misconception - User seems to be thinking, that differentiability of the function comes from its continuity, which is wrong, as we all know from trivial example $f(x)=|x|$.
It is in fact good, that @peek-a-boo mentioned that, because, of course things are vice-versa - continuity of the function comes from its differentiability, and hence, using the differentiability definition, one should may prove function continuity.
This is the key moment, because, again - continuity of differentiable function comes from the part of definition, that restricts differentiable function value growth linear part to be infinitely small, per infinitely small argument growth. This is exactly where function continuity comes from in term of its differentiability.
In the formulation before the "in other words" it is made as multiplying the derivative $A$ by infinitely small $x-a$, but in the "in other words" formulation, there is no such restriction, it states it only should be linear,

and hence allowing differentiable function value growth not to be infinitely small,
and hence allowing differentiable function not to be continuous,
and hence violates* previous definition,
and hence is not an "in other words" i.e. equivalent definition,
and hence is false.

. * - roughly, since "in other words" states nothing about how linear function should be, we can't state that it violates the original definition - according to the "in other words", differentiable function may or may not be continuous. If "in other words" formulation stated that differentiable function linear part should not be infinitely small, that will be exactly logical negotiation of the original definition, and hence 100% false.
However, actually we still can consider it as false, since it started from words "in other words", which means it should be equivalent, while, as we see is not, in part of cases.
So it is false in term of it is "in other words" at least.
